# SBT how to abstract away configuration?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have settings which looks like this

```
(scalatexSource in Compile) := (sourceDirectory in Compile).value / "scalatex",
(scalatexSource in Test) := (sourceDirectory in Test).value / "scalatex",
```

I'd have thought that I could declare it once as this:

```
scalatexSource := sourceDirectory.value / "scalatex",
```

to have it apply in all cases. However, it uselessly defaults to the root of `src/` each time, rather than `src/main/` and `src/test/` as I'd expect.

How can I remove the duplication and make sure the settings match regardless of what the `in` thing is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the unscoped settings (your guess), then send them through `inConfig` once for `Compile` and once for `Test`.

```
val configSettings = Seq(
  scalatexSource := sourceDirectory.value / "scalatex"
)

inConfig(Compile)(configSettings) ++
inConfig(Test)(configSettings)
```